# How to make a pdf link in Django

Tags: python, html, django, pdf, hyperlink

I'm extremely new to Django and I was hoping someone could help me add a link to my website which allows someone to download a pdf file. The pdf file is located here:
`static/files/offline_reg_form.pdf`
and I have no idea what the URL should be in the urls.py file or the view in the views.py file. I have looked around but nothing is working as I want it too.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will answer your questions.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

If it still confuses you,

`{% load static %}
<img src="{% static "my_app/example.jpg" %}" alt="My image"/>`

is an example of what should be in your **template**.

Answer (score 6):

For you specifically:

```
{% load static %}
<a href="{% static "files/offline_reg_form.pdf" %}">my pdf</a>
```